# Redis DB export/import

Tags: import, export, redis

Does anybody know a good solution for export/import in Redis?
Generally I need to dump DB (and edit the dump as a case) from a server and load it to another one (e.g. localhost).
Maybe some scripts?

Comment: Here is a github link to dump redis all keys or some specific keys to a json file and load data from json file. If you want, you can try this  https://github.com/asit-dhal/redis-dump-and-load

Comment: why is this too broad?

Comment: good article for redis backup and restore https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-redis-data-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Redis has two binary format files supported: RDB and AOF.

RDB is a dump like what you asked. You can call `save` to force a rdb. It will be stored in the `dbfilename` setting you have, or dump.rdb in the current working directory if that setting is missing.

More Info:
http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 14):

If you want a server to load the content from other server, no dump is required. You may use [slaveof](http://redis.io/commands/slaveof) to sync the data and once it's up to date call `slaveof no one`.

More information on replication can be found in this link: http://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: I need it to work for a localhost as well. Thanks

Comment: You can use it in two different instances of redis on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

you can try my dump util, [rdd](https://github.com/r043v/rdd), it extract or insert data into redis and can split, merge, filter, rename